# nmcli create security popup?

Tags: wifi, i3, nmcli

Is it possible to connect to a wifi network using nmcli without specifying a password so that it pops up with a security authentication message, The same as when you use nm-applet and try to connect to a wifi network that is password protected? Or would I have to use a different command for this to happen? If so what kind of command would I need?

For example I want to connect to wifi ssid: something123 and it's password protected.

when I do: `nmcli device wifi connect something123`
it will return

> Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.

I would like the cli to automatically create a popup where I can enter the credentials instead of having to put it in as a parameter.

This is essential for me because I'm trying to create a rofi menu for my i3 window manager where I can select a wifi network and connect to it through commands in a script.

Comment: You could use something like `dialog --inputbox "Password for something123:" 5 38`

Comment: This is not ideal because dialog will output it to the terminal and I need it to open up a window inside my window manager preferably a floating window with user input.

Comment: OK, is  `zenity --entry --text="Password for something123"` closer?

Comment: Hmmm yes, this seems like a good solution. I'll have to catch the user input in my script somehow but I guess I can figure it out from here. Thanks a lot!